# Use inferred property type in another property of the same object

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to do this in TypeScript?

**Note:** Any property name is valid in the `props` argument

```
type Values<T extends object> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, 'onStart'>>

declare function animate<T extends {
    onStart?: (values: Values<T>) => void
}>(props: T): void

animate({
    foo: 100,
    onStart(values) {
        // $Expect(values == { foo: number })
    }
})
```

[Playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QM4B4AqUIA9gQB2AJqlAPYBGAVhAMbAB8UAvFAAoCWdA1lgDRQAorjrJiEdDwghyAMyiZBAcnKEAysDgAnYMsaMAUIYlid0OUkINOaqHEKcAtnAJYc+IqSgBvQ1ACKDS1dAH4ALigACgA3RBRUSPhkNCxGAEpWZhjyTmJDAF9GKLBtcjBExXTInLzjB2dXCCi-QKg5cnJIgEYABl7+f0C1TR1gWPi0TNa2wIB6OagAEhFIBgmUshY2H3bOyMIkJ0oIbSgC9KGAgsL0oA)

Comment: Which is the inferred property type? For instance, are you trying to ensure that `values` has a property `foo` of type `number`?

Comment: Yes, that's what the `$Expect` comment is saying

Comment: Hmm, I doubt that this is possible.  I know I've seen it [said](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22149#issuecomment-369683733) that the compiler doesn't simultaneously infer a type parameter and apply the inferred parameter contextually.  Don't know if there's an official word about this case though.

Comment: @jcalz Strangely, you can do it, but not with function types ([see here](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAshBOBzCAeAggGigIQHxQF4oBvKAbQGkoBLAOygGsIQB7AMyjQF0AuKKiAA9gEWgBMAzo2bscUAPw5KXKHzTKoAXygAyHAChQkKAAVqAYwYAxeCwC2KACr4ijqEJHippNrbt86NgQoAFUtBVDVEk19fTEIcwAbAEN4aDYAV1pzYGoWemTaajtkkSd3YVFJKBYAIwArBOBcAAp9KA6oMFswCT44JFRHLFJgFnk+M0sbeyd8TVx9AEo+ADcWajFYwuLSiBbids7fez4fFhY+AEYtDCOOsbOoNgu+AHI38IB6L6gAORYuXM0GAAAtoAhbPAoMlaiwMsAoKCWAB3KAAIheLHRUDsGQkiNq0GSUFoGTsRPg+k0SyAA))

Comment: Actually, the only restriction is argument types. The return type works fine. ([see here](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAshBOBzCAeAggGigIQHxQF4oBvKAbQGkoBLAOygGsIQB7AMyjQF0AuKKiAA9gEWgBMAzo2bscUAPw5KXKHzTKoAXygAyHAChQkKAAVqAYwYAxeCwC2KACr4ijqEJHippNrbt86NgQoAFUtBVDVEk19fTEIcwAbAEN4aDYAV1pzYGoWemTaajtkkSd3YVFJEihfez5CkCx8gGVgVOAG2hAtXAAKfSghqDBbMAk+OCRURyxSVvb4YHk+PoBKQnwzSxt7J3xNXH01vgA3FmoxWMLi0og+4kHhuv8athYWPgBGLQwnoYWHXWJH+wyGaWAGXg9GI70+UAA5AiYmCYpo1kA))